# Leading Zero missing when cast to decimal

Tags: php, sql

Below is my SQL query. I already cast it to convert decimal up to 2 decimal point. But when value is leading number is zero it shows ".##" where '#" is number.

SQL query:
`CAST(SHIFTCLOSING.OPENINGAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS OPENINGAMOUNT`

Value 12.35486 ==> output in PHP 12.35 (OK)

Value 0.34845 ==> output in PHP .3484 (0 is not displayed)

Comment: how you display the results in php? also format your question properly./

Comment: I echo out the values. Anyway I found the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL `FORMAT` then set the pattern to `'0.##'`, it will force the leading zero when missing.

```
FORMAT(CAST(SHIFTCLOSING.OPENINGAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18,2)), '0.##') AS OPENINGAMOUNT
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting a string from your database. You could try forcing a format using PHP's `printf()` function.

If you use `printf('%.4f', '0.34845')` (the `%f` is for displaying a float value and the `.4` is setting four decimal digits) you'll get a string with a leading zero `0.3484`. You could also use `sprintf()` instead if you wish to set that value to a variable, just beware it will be a string instead of a number.

Comment: I used `'0.34845'` as the second argument just to illustrate, you should use the actual variable with the value that you've retrieved from the database.